# prove a sequence $(f_n(x))_{n=1}^\infty$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convergence-divergence

I am new to math stack exchange. I have been introduced to functions $f_{1},f_{2},f_{3}...$, domain is $[0, \infty)$, and just summarized as $$f_{n}(x)=\begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{n} & \text{if } x \in [0, n) \\
      \frac{-1}{n}x+1+\frac{1}{n} & \text{if } x \in [n, n+1) \\
      0 & \text{if } x \in [n+1, \infty) \\
   \end{cases}$$

How do I prove a sequence $(f_n(x))_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to the function $f:[0, \infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=0, \forall x\in [0, \infty)$?

This form of the question is very confusing, so I think it is better changing it to:
$$\forall x \in [0, \infty), \lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)=f(x).$$
What are the next steps?

Comment: For any $x$ the inequality $x<n$ holds for all $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: Notice that $0\leq f_n(x)\leq \frac{1}{n}$ for each $x$.

Comment: Just compute the limit of $f_n(x)$ for every 'fixed' $x \in [0, +\infty)$

Comment: In the $\frac{-1}{n}x+1+\frac{1}{n}$ function it should not be $\frac{-1}{n}x+\frac{1}{n}$ ¿?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we would want to start with the pointwise limit. Taking the limit as n tends to infinity we get:
Let $x$ be a real number. Then there exists $n  \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x<n$. Then
$$\lim f_{n}(x)=\lim{\frac{1}{n}}=0$$
Thus, the only candidate for an uniform limit is the function $f(x)=0$. We have that:
$$||f_n-f||_{x\in\mathbb{R}}>0$$ This holds for all $\mathbb{N}$, since there is a part of the function (in a set of nonzero measure for al $n\in\mathbb{N}$) that is a line different from the constant line $y=0$, so the sequence does not converge uniformly.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But, I want to wait for other people to see it, and maybe answer too.